# Correct way to POST date to datetime in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, date, datetime

I have created a form that sends data to a database, all fields are working except date, i assume it is to do with the format but i am unsure how to go about it?

HTML

```
<dt>Date of Purchase</dt>
        <dd>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[date_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
            </select>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[date_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[date_of_purchase]">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            </select>
    </dd>
```

PHP

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `registration` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_purchase`) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_purchase)');                  

$stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
$stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
$stmt->param(':date_of_purchase', $post['date_of_purchase']);
```

Comment: Your selects overwrite one another. Use different names and construct the full date from the received data in your script.

Comment: You're trying to insert an array into a parameter? What's the type of date_of_purchase in the database?

Comment: `id`s as well as `name`s should be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use different names for fields

```
<dt>Date of Purchase</dt>
        <dd>
            <select id="month_of_purchase" name="month_of_purchase">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
            </select>
            <select id="day_of_purchase" name="day_of_purchase">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select id="year_of_purchase" name="year_of_purchase">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            </select>
    </dd>
```

and then construct date as

```
$stmt->param(':date_of_purchase', sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $post['day_of_purchase'], $post['month_of_purchase'], $post['year_of_purchase']));
```

(i assume that $post['year_of_purchase'] is the same as $_POST['year_of_purchase'])

Comment: Thanks alot, this worked for me after i just changed the order to `$stmt->param(':date_of_purchase', sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $post['year_of_purchase'], $post['month_of_purchase'], $post['day_of_purchase']));` as the format in my database was year-month-day

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

HTML

```
<dt>Date of Purchase</dt>
        <dd>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[month]">
            <option value="">Month</option>
            <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
            <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
            <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
            </select>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[day]">
            <option value="">Day</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            <select id="date_of_purchase" name="entry[year]">
            <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            </select>
    </dd>
```

PHP

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `registration` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `date_of_purchase`) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_purchase)');                  

$stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
$stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
$stmt->param(':date_of_purchase', $post['month'] . $post['day'] . $post['year']); // Just an example, I am pretty sure this won't work, change it according to your database
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it could be :

```
//in PHP
//first : convert and valid the INPUT
try{
    $date = DateTime.CreateFromFormat("d-m-Y",$post["day"]."-".$post["month"]."-".$post['year']);
    //then you will convert it to MySQL format :
     $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `registration` (`first_name`, `last_name`,  `date_of_purchase`) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :date_of_purchase)');                  

     $stmt->param(':first_name', $post['first_name']);
     $stmt->param(':last_name', $post['last_name']);
     $stmt->param(':date_of_purchase', $date->format("Y-m-d h:i:s"); 
}catch(Exception $e){
   //here re-ask the date because it is false
}
```